# commandButton click in p:dataTable causes @ViewScoped bean to be re@Produced after application invocation

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish, cdi, view-scope

### The view:

```
<h:form ...
  <p:dataTable value="#{myBean.list}" var="data" ...
     <p:column ...
        <h:commandButton action="#{controller.method(data.id)}" />
     </p:column>
  </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

### The controller:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Controller {
   public String method(final Long dataId) {
        /* Do business */
        return URL_WITH_REDIRECT;
   }
}
```

### The producer

(using the `@ViewScoped` CDI annotation as described [here](http://www.verborgh.be/articles/2010/01/06/porting-the-viewscoped-jsf-annotation-to-cdi/))

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Producer {
   @Named @ViewScoped @Producer
   public MyBean getMyBean() {
        final MyBean bean = new MyBean();
        bean.list = new ArrayList<Data>(); // where Data has a Long id field
        /* Do business and populate list */
        return bean;
   }
}
```

## The problem & its scenario

1. `GET` the page

   1. The bean is produced
   2. View is rendered
   3. Response sent to browser
2. Click the button

   1. Data is `POST`ed to server
   2. [Phases](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-bC8QIZcP5Zs/TuKqFu4_QkI/AAAAAAAAAR8/oRgEtTDXohc/s1600/jsf-lifecycle-viewstate.JPG) 1-4 are executed without any issue, and that use `@ViewScoped` beans as expected
   3. Phase 5: `controller.method` is called with `data.id` and accesses beans generated at **1.1**
   4. Method returns redirect `String`
   5. **!! The producer is called again !!** - we're still in APPLICATION_INVOCATION phase, but after the actual method call
3. Browser receives redirect
4. `GET` next page ...

#### The half-"donkey" solution that works:

In short: on click, copy the id outside the datatable, and trigger a click on a submit button.

On the `h:commandButton` inside the table column added :

```
onclick="$('input[id*=selectedDataId]').val('#{data.id}'); $('button[id*=callMethod]').trigger('click');"
```

Outside the table:

```
<h:inputHidden id="{selectedDataId}"binding="#{selectedDataId}"/>
<p:commandButton type="submit"
                 id="callMethod"
                 label="Hidden button"
                 action="#{controller.method(selectedDataId.value)}"/>
```

At the end it works, but I was not able to figure out what causes the first & base approach to reinitialize the view scoped bean. Looking at the stack trace (see below) it seems like it is rebuilding the rows.

#### Question:

Does anyone have an explanation, and maybe caveats to look out for regarding this issue?

#### Stack trace

Where: `getPipelinecheckSearchResults` is the call for retrieving the list that backs the table, that causes the producer to be called

[image: stack trace]

#### What I've already looked through:

I've read following articles / SO questions without gaining any better understanding on why the above (1st) solution works as it does.

[ViewScoped bean is recreated everytime I click on commandButton in my dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500439/viewscoped-bean-is-recreated-everytime-i-click-on-commandbutton-in-my-datatable)

[Why does @PostConstruct callback fire every time even though bean is @ViewScoped? JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797231/why-does-postconstruct-callback-fire-every-time-even-though-bean-is-viewscoped)

[How can I pass selected row to commandLink inside dataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994458/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-commandlink-inside-a-datatable)

http://balusc.blogspot.de/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html

https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1492

Comment: oh nice, I think I recently observed a similar behaviour

Comment: did you try to call a method of __myBean__ instead of __controller__ from _commandButton action_?

Comment: did you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675319/session-scoped-managed-bean-and-actionlistener

Comment: 1. Tried calling method off of `myBean`. Same issue. (Though I wouldn't put logic into models, since they should be dumb). 
2. Yes read it, but that refers to `actionListener`, and in my case, the re`@Produc`tion is **after** the APPLICATION_INVOCATION, so `action` finds its way correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found some sources for jsf/primefaces/ee-api/glassfish etc. to debug the behavior, so here's the answer:

## In short

#### If a `component`:

- Triggers an action (`controller.method`) that **causes redirect**
- And is placed in a `datatable`
- And the `datatable` generates its rows based on a `@ViewScoped` bean

#### Then:

- After the `controller.method` invocation the `@ViewScoped` bean that the `datatable` depends on will be regenerated (with all its dependencies of course)

Tested: In version `2.1.7` of JSF. 
Looked in sources of `2.1.19`, and I'd expect same behavior there.

## Details

For those who cry out loud in lonely summer nights asking: "*Why?*"

#### The chain of "Events" that lead to this behavior (with references to sources):

1. The user clicks a button inside a table row.
2. Data is `POST`ed to the server
3. Phases 1-4 go as planned
4. `APPLICATION_INVOCATION`

   1. The click event is received by JSF. **Important:** The click event that references the button is wrapped in an event that contains information about the table & the row number the click happened on. For simplicity: `rowEvent & clickEvent`
   2. The event is "broadcasted" in the tree of the components @ [`UIViewRoot:794`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-api/2.1.7/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.java?av=f)
   3. `javax.faces.UIData` The grandparent of `org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable` backing `p:datatable` starts processing the event @ [`UIData.broadcast(FacesEvent)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-api/2.1.7/javax/faces/component/UIData.java?av=f)

      1. The `broadcast` method first saves the index of the last selected row
      2. Then it selects the one specified by the `rowEvent`
      3. Dispatches the `clickEvent` on the child `UIComponent`, in our case on the `Button`

         1. Everything is well & fine, and the event starts getting processed by [`ActionListener.processAction(ActionEvent)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.6/com/sun/faces/application/ActionListenerImpl.java#ActionListenerImpl)

            1. This in turn invokes `controller.method` which returns a redirect `String` and things begin to go downhill
            2. At the end of the method the `redirectString` is processed by a [`NavigationHandler`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.7/com/sun/faces/application/NavigationHandlerImpl.java#NavigationHandlerImpl)

               1. This one seeing that we're about to redirect quickly clears the `ViewMap` removing all `@ViewScoped` beans from it at line `179`. Which if we think about it is kind of logical, since we're on our way out.
      4. On arriving back in `UIData.broadcast` which

         - having broadcasted the inner event,
         - not knowing that some inner event caused a redirect and everything it does will be thrown to the garbage (because of `302`)
         - as a last action, tries to select the row whose index it saved at step `4.3.1`
      5. And of course to select a row, it needs to know the data for it, and this is where the `@ViewScoped` bean(s) needed by the table get regenerated.

*THE END*

### Notice

Though I haven't tested I'd expect the same behavior `h:datatable`, `p:accordionPanel`, `p:carousel`, `p:galleria`, `p:dataGrid` etc. In short every component that subclasses `UIData` and doesn't provide a `redirect` - aware `broadcast` method.

Comment: Hi. Same problem here, but I think it is a Primefaces issue. If I use plain JSF tags (I mean h:datatable and so on), all works ok. Did you find any solution? Primefaces even doesn't work if "action method" returns "null" (which wouldn't fire the recreation of the Viewscoped bean.

Comment: Even more... my problem is when I click the p:commandbutton to edit a row of the 2nd, 3rd, etc pages of the primefaces datable. If I edit a row of the first row, it works ok, the Viewscoped bean isn't recreated.

Comment: Adding log info to trace, I've discovered that the "action method" isn't called when I click the p:commandbutton of the 2nd or following pages of the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm understanding this incorrectly you're using a bean that is scoped to the view somehow (Seam 3, CODI, or your own custom scope you've written). You're fine as long as the JSF life cycle is operating on the same view (which would be a correct assumption), but you're surprised when you change the view id that you get a new instance of the view scoped bean?? The whole purpose of the view scope is to keep things in the same view state in JSF, as soon as you tell JSF to go to a different view id it creates a new view state. Sounds to me what you're actually looking for is the conversation scope.

Comment: The used `@ViewScope` is the one [described here][1]

[1] http://www.verborgh.be/articles/2010/01/06/porting-the-viewscoped-jsf-annotation-to-cdi/

Comment: On the other hand: If you check the **Scenario** above, the problem is that the producer is called before the *actual* redirect that is sent to the browser (between steps **2.4** and **3**. So we are still in the `POST` request, that originates from the click, and which successfully uses `@ViewsScoped` beans produced in step **1.1**. + I am aware that once navigating away from the page, or losing or not using the right `ViewState` id on the client side leads to losing all `@ViewScoped`. Unfortunately this is not the problem, since phases 1-4 and the method call works and finds these beans.

Comment: Moreover: Everything works as expected using the workaround described above (If I move the `h/p:commandButton` outside the `p:dataTable`)

Comment: Hm, I wonder what the AJAX call is sending. It's possible something is missing from the request.

Comment: Same behavior with/without AJAX + checked the POSTed data, and contains the correct ViewState (that's why everything in the first 4 phases work) and don't cause producer executions

Comment: Which phase is changing the viewid? I'd expect that to be during invoke_application.

Comment: I've managed to scrap together sources for my ee stack and debugged the problem. See my answer & thank you for your time.